# How can I use dash with multiple words in Yii2 page creation

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to create a static page with Yii2. The page name has more has two words for example - privacy policy. I added the code below inside `SiteController.php`

```
public function actionPrivacyPolicy()
{
    return $this->render('privacy-policy');
}
```

I then created a page inside the site folder named - `privacy-policy.php`
This however resulted in page not found error.
My website has many cases like this. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: if you have turned the `enablePrettyUrl=>true` then you should type in `http://yoursite.com/site/privacy-policy`, if not then `http://yoursite.com/index.php?r=site/privacy-policy` and you dont need to match the `view` name with the `action` it can be anything.

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam .Yes I have I enabled `enablePrettyUrl=>true`. I tested`http://yoursite.com/site/privacy-policy` and it worked! But I am confused because I added a rule `'<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',` to get rid of `site` in the url and it works for links with one word. For example, both `http://yoursite.com/site/contact` and `http://yoursite.com/site/contact` works but `http://yoursite.com/privacy-policy` without `site` throws up page not found. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Any idea please?

Comment: added an answer see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the url like below if using `"enablePrettyUrl"=>true`

- `http://yoursite.com/site/privacy-policy`

and

- `http://yoursite.com/index.php?r=site/privacy-policy`

if not using `"enablePrettyUrl"=>true`

after that you need to parse all the actions in `SiteController` by the action names only, so you need to turn `"enableStrictParsing"=>false` and then add the following rule in the `urlManager`

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    "enableStrictParsing" => false,
    'rules' => [
        "/" => "site/index",
        "<action:(.*)>" => 'site/<action>',
    ],
],
```

**EDIT:**

Although this allows characters that are/should not be allowed but, The reason I have used `(.*)` in the rules is because the action name will be defined inside the controllers and you have to use the rules with the declared actions only inside the `SiteController` which isn't going to parse any action name for rules with any of the disallowed characters, means if the action name is going to be, say `actionMyActionNameLong` there is 0 possibility that any `/` or `\` is generated with the action name which would break the things further when using the rule, so you can use it in this context otherwise you can use the `[\w\-]+` if creating the urls manually.

Comment: can you look at rob006 contribution below? Have you considered the point raised? I think you may wish to fine-tune this answer to avoid causing problem down the road for others.

Comment: @atsngr, rob006 has answered in context to the given token `\w+` that you have used which will allow only **Any word Character** and not `-` which is correct according to his answer. Whereas `.*` matches **any character (except for line terminators)** so technically `(.*)` will catch everything  `[\w\-]+` is capturing, isnt it working correctly for you?

Comment: very well. Your response has caused me to review the configuration of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern `<alias:\w+>` will not match hyphen, since `\w+` will accept only letters, numbers and underscore. You need to use `[\w\-]+` to match also words separated by hyphen.

```
'rules' => [
    '<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
    // ...
],
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But @Muhammad Omer Aslam answer did the job.

Comment: @atsngr In his answer there is `(.*)` used as a pattern, which is incorrect - it will catch all possible characters (including `/`), which is incorrect in this context. His rule basically breaks default fallback and every further rule.

Comment: Just tested your code too and it worked also. Considering that you already thought of possible effect for further rules, I think your contribution is very important

Answer (score -1):

I think you can configure UrlManager in main.php on the config folder
and try to add some rules on urlManager so the URL can be accessed dynamically

```
'urlManager' => [
            "enablePrettyUrl" => true,
            "showScriptName" => false,
            "enableStrictParsing" => false,
            "suffix" => "",
            "rules" => [
                "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>" => "<controller>/<action>"
            ],
        ],
```

If you are using \yii\filters\AccessControl on your controllers behaviour, you might need to add allowed action to the list before creating a new action.

Comment: Please see my comment above.